# Worker or set troops to mine first?

Tags: starcraft-2

Which is better in the start of a Starcraft II match? 
Build a worker and then split or vice versa; split workers then build worker

If they each have their own benefits please list them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really? [it doesn't really matter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-begin-gathering-at-the-start-of-a-game-of-star).

However, if you think about it, having six workers returning with minerals half seconds faster isn't as good in the long run as having a worker created half seconds earlier - as that delays all future workers by those precious half seconds.

However, if you need that pylon down or that supply depot out a half second faster, make sure to follow this precise order:

- Send your workers to work
- Create your next worker
- Split your workers as they are reaching their mining nodes.

Of course, screwing up any other action by a half second will undo all this precision.

Comment: Worker splitting is proven to not improve your gathering rate whatsoever.

Comment: Gathering rate no, however in the early game it gives you something like 10 extra minerals.